# My bot cannot access to blob storage account with a system assigned managed identity

Tags: javascript, botframework, azure-storage

I'm exploring using Azure blob storage with my bot. I'd like to use it as a persistent store for state, as well as storing transcripts.

I configure the `BlobStorage` object like this:

```js
storageProvider = new BlobStorage( {
  containerName: process.env.BlobContainerName,
  storageAccountOrConnectionString: process.env.BlobConnectionString
} );
```

As sensitive information is stored in these files, especially transcripts, I'm working with my team on securing the storage account and the container within it.

We have created a system assigned managed identity for the application service hosting the bot, and we have given this account the 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role. Which, as I understand it, provides read, write and delete access to content stored.

Unfortunately when the bot tries to access the storage the access attempt fails. I see the following error in the 'OnTurnError trace':

`StorageError: Forbidden`

Interestingly running the bot locally with the same blob storage connection string works. Suggesting that this issue is related to the service identity and/or the permissions that it has.

Does anyone know what could be causing the error? Are more permissions required to the storage account? Any thoughts on increasing the logging of the error to potentially see a more detailed error message is also most welcome.

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: Hi @ranusharao, As I've mentioned in my answer to my post, I don't believe the bot framework currently supports using identities to access blob storage. I've detailed my reasoning in the answer. Please let me know if I've missed anything in my analysis.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment in time I do not believe that the framework supports using a system assigned managed identity for access to the blob storage.

In looking into this I found a number of examples of Node.js that use two specific packages for accessing blob storage using a system assigned identity. Specifically:

- @azure/storage-blob - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob
- @azure/identity - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/identity

The identity package is the one that provides the functionality to get a token associated with a credential, that is then used by code in the storage-blob package to interact with the storage account.

If I look at the dependency tree for the bot framework I don’t see either of these packages. Instead I see:

- azure-storage - https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage
- botbuilder-azure - https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-azure

Taking a deep dive into these two packages I don’t see any code for connecting to an azure storage account that uses a credential. The only code I can find uses access keys. Therefore my conclusion currently is that the bot framework doesn’t support accessing a storage account using a credential.

While we could explore adding code that uses these packages, such significant development work is outside the scope of our project at present.

If anyone with more knowledge than I can see that this is incorrect please let me know via a comment and I'll explore further.

For the moment we have settled on continuing to use access keys. As it is not any less secure than the way the bot accesses other services. Such as the cognitive services like QnA Maker.